# Сбербанк реагирует на приложение

Tags: android, антивирус

На устройствах под управлением EMUI 11 версии антивирус сбербанка жалуется на приложение нашей компании выдавая ошибку `not-a-virus:HEUR.RiskTool.AndroidOS.subspod.a`. Проверили приложение на разных устройствах с разными антивирусами -  ничего не обнаружено. Разрешения, который запрашивает наше приложение

````
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />```
````

Comment: RECORD_AUDIO is considered a "dangerous" permission because it may pose a risk to the user's privacy. Вот вас и записали в категорию RiskTool.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
Вам это действительно нужно? Попробуйте убрать эту строчку

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я перед использованием проверяю, есть ли разрешение на запись аудио 
```if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // Запрос на разрешение
        } else {
            // Запись
            }
        } ```

Comment: И что? Это гарантирует что вы не будете втихаря писать юзера и отправлять на сервер, когда разрешение уже получено?

Comment: @woesss запись происходит при удержании на иконке, после того как удержание прекращено запись останавливается

Comment: Вы хоть в курсе, что искусственный интеллект - всё ещё научная фантастика? Никакой алгоритм не может 100% определить безопасно ваше приложение или нет. Антивирусы сверяют код приложений с базой данных уже известных вредоносов и потенциальных угроз. Поэтому вашему приложению выдан вердикт: `not-a-virus` (совпадений по базе вирусов нет) и `RiskTool` (потенциально опасно). Кажется там под капотом каспер - я бы посоветовал спросить у них на форуме что это за категория угроз такая. Может ваше приложение открывает лазейку для зловредов или это гипотетическая угроза из-за используемого функционала.

Comment: @woesss я понимаю что антивирус на телефоне - это пустая трата ресурсов телефона. В поисковиках не нашел ни одного упоминания данного текста. Писал в касперский и сбербанк. Касперский ответил, что это ошибочное срабатывание и оно будет исправлено. Сбербанк пока молчит. И да, я слышал на многих форумах, что под капотом сбербанка работает касперский

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что предыдущий кодер настроил так, что по тапу на номер (TextView) сразу совершается звонок. Я убрал эту реализацию и в данный момент у меня просто открывается звонилка с уже вставленным номером телефона